# Merge rows in dataset based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with this data frame which is a sample of data that I've pulled from my real data, which is the "finished product" after merging various CSV files.

```
reality = pd.DataFrame({"ProductID": ["016193625","016193625","016215677","016215677","016259859","016259859"],
                        "CountofProduct": [130.0, 130.0, 16,16, 38,38],
                        "InDF1": [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        "InDF2": [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        "InDF3": [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        "InDF4": [2,2,0,0,0,0],
                        "InDF5": [4,4,0,0,0,0],
                        "InFile1":[0,"Y","Y","Y",0,"Y",],
                        "InFile2":[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        "InFile3":[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        "InFile4":[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        "InFile5":[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                        "InFile6":["Y",0,0,0,"Y",0]})
```

the issue as you can see, is that my data is not amalgamating the product ID's into one line like this:

```
expectation = pd.DataFrame({"ProductID": ["016193625","016215677","016259859"], 
"CountofProduct": [130.0, 16, 38],
"InDF1": [0,0,0,],
"InDF2": [0,0,0,],
"InDF3": [0,0,0,],
"InDF4": [2,2,0,],
"InDF5": [4,0,0,],
"InFile1":["Y","Y",0], 
"InFile2":[0,0,0],
"InFile3":[0,0,0],
"InFile4":[0,0,0],
"InFile5":[0,0,0],
"InFile6":["Y",0,"Y"]})
```

Is there a way within Pandas to achieve this result?

As I understand it, the reason this seems to have happened is because one of my source files had sufficiently different rows for the product ID, when I did the merge, it seems that even though the product ID's are the same, the data within the rows are different.

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby:

```
reality.groupby('ProductID', as_index=False).agg('first')
```

output would be:

```
    ProductID   CountofProduct  InDF1   InDF2   InDF3   InDF4   InDF5   InFile1 InFile2 InFile3 InFile4 InFile5 InFile6
0   016193625   130.0   0   0   0   2   4   0   0   0   0   0   Y
1   016215677   16.0    0   0   0   0   0   Y   0   0   0   0   0
2   016259859   38.0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
```

Comment: This almost works, but I think because it only takes the first instance within the DF it causes some of the data from subsequent rows to be lost that needs to be captured (016193625 should have a "Y" in the column "InFile1" but it was dropped.

Comment: No, it doesn't lose it. it just picks the first one out of two iterative values. the problem is you didn't specify how you picked [0,"Y","Y","Y",0,"Y",] and converted into [Y,Y,0] and in "InFile6":["Y",0,0,0,"Y",0] how you picked [Y,0,Y] is it whenever it sees 0,Y should pick Y?

Comment: Yes that is correct, if there is a Y value, it should pick Y.

Answer (score 0):

```py
reality.drop_duplicates(subset="CountofProduct")
```

```
   ProductID  CountofProduct  InDF1  InDF2  ...  InFile3  InFile4  InFile5 InFile6
0  016193625           130.0      0      0  ...        0        0        0       Y
2  016215677            16.0      0      0  ...        0        0        0       0
4  016259859            38.0      0      0  ...        0        0        0       Y

[3 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: Hi Laurent, unfortunately this is a similar result to the problem below, what I am trying to do is to merge the duplicate instances as there is data that is lost when dropping.

Comment: Hi conrito345 your problem is not not clear. Type of merging is summing, replacing, ignoring when there already is a value in first row ?